# Heroku can not compile Symfony2 project

Tags: php, symfony, heroku

I'm trying to deploy project first time and I don't know what to do with this error. 
Here is the output:

```
anna@anna-X550LA:~/jobfy$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 479, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (299/299), done.
Writing objects: 100% (479/479), 1.04 MiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 479 (delta 269), reused 312 (delta 157)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> PHP app detected
remote: -----> Bootstrapping...
remote: -----> Installing platform packages...
remote:        - php (7.0.4)
remote:        - apache (2.4.18)
remote:        - nginx (1.8.1)
remote: 
remote:  !     WARNING: Your 'composer.lock' is not up to date with the latest
remote:        changes in 'composer.json'. To ensure you are not getting stale
remote:        dependencies, run 'composer update' on your machine and commit
remote:        any changes to Git before pushing again.
remote: 
remote: -----> Installing dependencies...
remote:        Composer version 1.0.0-beta1 2016-03-03 15:15:10
remote:        Loading composer repositories with package information
remote:        Installing dependencies from lock file
remote:          - Installing doctrine/lexer (v1.0.1)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing doctrine/annotations (v1.2.7)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing twig/twig (v1.24.0)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing symfony/symfony (v2.8.3)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing symfony/security-acl (v2.8.0)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing symfony/polyfill-util (v1.1.1)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing paragonie/random_compat (v1.2.2)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing symfony/polyfill-php70 (v1.1.1)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing symfony/polyfill-php56 (v1.1.1)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing ircmaxell/password-compat (v1.0.4)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing symfony/polyfill-php55 (v1.1.1)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing symfony/polyfill-php54 (v1.1.1)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing symfony/polyfill-mbstring (v1.1.1)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing symfony/polyfill-intl-icu (v1.1.1)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing symfony/polyfill-apcu (v1.1.1)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing psr/log (1.0.0)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing doctrine/inflector (v1.1.0)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing doctrine/collections (v1.3.0)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing doctrine/cache (v1.5.4)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing doctrine/common (v2.5.3)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing jdorn/sql-formatter (v1.2.17)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle (1.3.0)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing doctrine/dbal (v2.5.4)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing doctrine/doctrine-bundle (1.6.2)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing doctrine/orm (v2.4.8)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing friendsofsymfony/user-bundle (dev-master 16b04c4)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing incenteev/composer-parameter-handler (v2.1.2)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing sensiolabs/security-checker (v3.0.2)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing sensio/distribution-bundle (v5.0.5)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing sensio/framework-extra-bundle (v3.0.14)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing monolog/monolog (1.18.1)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing symfony/monolog-bundle (v2.10.0)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing swiftmailer/swiftmailer (v5.4.1)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:          - Installing symfony/swiftmailer-bundle (v2.3.11)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:        Generating optimized autoload files
remote:        > Incenteev\ParameterHandler\ScriptHandler::buildParameters
remote:        Creating the "app/config/parameters.yml" file
remote:        > Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap
remote:        > Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache
remote:        
remote:                                                                                     
remote:          [Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException]                              
remote:          An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused  
remote:                                                                                     
remote:        
remote:                                                     
remote:          [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]        
remote:          SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused  
remote:                                                     
remote:        
remote:                                                     
remote:          [PDOException]                             
remote:          SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused  
remote:                                                     
remote:        
remote:        Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the post-install-cmd event terminated with an exception
remote:        
remote:                                                                                         
remote:          [RuntimeException]                                                             
remote:          An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command:      
remote:                                                                                         
remote:            [Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException]                                
remote:            An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused    
remote:                                                                                         
remote:                                                                                         
remote:            [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]                                          
remote:            SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused                                    
remote:                                                                                         
remote:                                                                                         
remote:            [PDOException]                                                               
remote:            SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused                                    
remote:                                                                                         
remote:          .                                                                              
remote:                                                                                         
remote:        
remote:        install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<packages>]...
remote:        
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile PHP app
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to pacific-tor-55653.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/pacific-tor-55653.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/pacific-tor-55653.git'
```

It is config.yml file:

```
imports:
- { resource: parameters.yml }
- { resource: security.yml }
- { resource: services.yml }
- { resource: "@JobFyBundle/Resources/config/services.yml" }

# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed
# 

http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#application-related-configuration
parameters:
    locale: en

framework:
    #esi:             ~
    #translator:      { fallbacks: ["%locale%"] }
    secret:          "%secret%"
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    #serializer:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_hosts:   ~
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:
        # handler_id set to null will use default session handler from php.ini
        handler_id:  ~
    fragments:       ~
    http_method_override: true

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   pdo_pgsql
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
        #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
        #     e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
        #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
        #   3. Uncomment next line:
        #     path:     "%database_path%"

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"

fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: JobFyBundle\Entity\User
```

I use Ubuntu 14.04, Symfony2.8, Php 5.6
I'm not sure what else you may need, so I'll add it if there will be questions.
Thank's for help!

Comment: have you followed the instructions on http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/deployment/heroku.html

Comment: Yes, I have, but I still have this problem.

Comment: Looks like it can't connect to the database. You sure you have created it with a user with the right access?

Comment: Look at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql